# React UI Kitten Styling TabBars

Tags: react-native, tabbar, react-native-ui-kitten

Pretty simple question and concept here, I am using the react UI Kitten Framework for a React Native Project, and for the life of me I cannot change the styling on the `TabBar`'s `Tab` components. I've looked at the documentation, and this is where it had lead me...

```
 <View style={LandingPageStyles.container}>
            <View style={LandingPageStyles.tabBarContainer}>
                <TabBar
                    indicatorStyle={{color: '#ffffff !important', borderColor: '#ffffff !important'}}
                    tabBarStyle={LandingPageStyles.loginTab}
                    style={LandingPageStyles.tabBar}
                    selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
                    onSelect={index => setSelectedIndex(index)}
                >
                    <Tab 
                        title="Login" 
                        tabBarStyle={LandingPageStyles.loginTab}
                        indicatorStyle={{color: '#ffffff !important', borderColor: '#ffffff !important'}}
                        tabBarStyle={LandingPageStyles.loginTab}/>
                    <Tab 
                        title='Sign Up' 
                        tabBarStyle={LandingPageStyles.signUpTab}
                        indicatorStyle={{color: '#ffffff !important', borderColor: '#ffffff !important'}}
                        tabBarStyle={LandingPageStyles.loginTab}/>
                </TabBar>
            </View>
            <View>
                {determineRender()}
            </View>
        </View>
```

And I have the following styleSheets...

```
const LandingPageStyles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: maxWidth,
        height: maxHeight,
    },
    tabBarContainer: {
        marginTop: maxHeight * 0.045,
        marginLeft: maxWidth * 0.075,
        marginBottom: maxHeight * 0.06,

        // borderWidth: 1,
        // borderColor: 'black',
        // width: maxWidth * 0.85,
    },
    tabBar: {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(52, 52, 52, 0.3) !important',
    },
    loginTab: {
        borderBottomColor: "white",
        color: 'white',
    },
    signUpTab: {
        borderBottomColor: "white",
        color: 'white',
    }
})
```

Notice that I'm attempting to style the tabs themselves in anyway possible, adding `style` `tabBarStyle` and `indicatorStyle` anywhere it would be relevant. Unfortunately it does nothing and the text color is still some faded blue/grey instead of white, and the borderBottomColor of the selected tab is just blue. Am I shit out of luck an unable to style Kitten elements or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

For Changing certain styles in the react native ui kitten library, you would need to use something known as **customize mappings**.

You can follow the guide here:

1. [Custom Component Mapping](https://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/design-system/custom-component-mapping#create-a-custom-component-mapping)
2. Customizing mappinghttps://akveo.github.io/react-native-ui-kitten/docs/design-system/customize-mapping#customize-component-mapping

Answer (score 0):

The tabview styles are very limited, your styles are ignored/overridden.
Customize component mapping is very cumbersome, lack of documentation, moreover you can't change the layout.
You have to render the components by yourself to fully control the styling

```js
<TabView indicatorStyle={yourStyle} tabBarStyle={yourStyle}>
<Tab style={yourTabStyle}
    /* instead of passing the string, you pass the function to render the title */
    title={() => <Text style={yourTitleStyle}>Tab1</Text>}
    /* same for icon */
    icon={() => <Icon name='star' style={yourIconStyle}/>} 
>
</TabView>
```